# Call static TypeScript function out of HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript, function

I want to call a static class method/function from out of my HTML in Angular 7. This function is not in the `component.ts` but in a separate general class file `message.ts`.
An error is displayed on the console :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'msg1' of undefined.
```

Template:

```html
<div>
  {{ Message.msg1({ 'x': 'abc', 'y': 'def' }) }}
</div>
```

`message.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class Message {

        constructor() { }

        public static msg1 (items: []): string {
          // some code
        }
    }
```

Is what I want possible ? If yes, how can I get the message file (and so the Message class) in scope of the HTML?

Comment: What is the purpose?

Comment: You should use services for this

Comment: It is bad idea: if some property changed in your Message object, then  template will be broken and you don't know about it;

Comment: Do you want that Message class as a global class and by which you can use a method of that class anywhere?

Comment: @Niraj Oza : yes, that's the purpose

Comment: You can use pure javascript if you don't require any http calls or dependency on angular modules. just define class with static method and use it. If you want example then I will add as an answer

Comment: @Niraj Oza : thanks, but I think I will go forward with the answer of jonrsharpe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static methods are accessible on the *class*, not the instance injected by DI. If you want that template code to work, you'd have to do e.g.

```
import { Message } from ".../message";

@Component(...)
class Whatever {
  Message = Message;

   ...
}
```

to make the class available as Message in the template scope.

That said, it's unclear why that method is static, or what the point of an injectable service with only a static method is.

Comment: Yes, this works ... but at the end of the day I would like to have that Message class as a global class which I can use anywhere (html, component, service) without having to import/instantiatie/declare it.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, then; only components and pipes declared in the module and public properties on the component class are accessible from the template.